# Mac OS X - shortcut for changing text color?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

does anyone know the shortcut to change the text color on Word 2011 on a Mac?

I would like to ideally select a part of the text, press a key combination, and change the color of the text to the color in the Font toolbar.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard key, but you can assign one via Tools->Customize keyboard..., select Format in the left column, locate and select FontColor in the right column, then assign a key (make sure you actually click the Assign button. Then, if you also want a "set to Auto color" keystroke, select the Color: command in the Format list. A color dropdown will appear at the top right of the dialog box. Ensure Auto is selected (or select the color you want) and assign a keystroke to that.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not exactly what you want it can set the text colour to the automatic colour of microsoft word. It's a small applescript code.

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    tell active window
        set color index of font object of text object of selection to auto
    end tell
end tell
```

Open up Applescript Editor and save it to `~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/Word Script Menu Items` as what ever you want then open up System Preferences.

In System Preferences go to `Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts` The press the + sign at under the list of shortcuts. Next select Microsoft word from the application drop down. For the Menu item name it exactly what you called your script minus the extension. Finally choose a shortcut and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Tools >> Customize Keyboard >> Categorize (choose format) >> Commands (find Font Color) >> Fill the shortcut bar with any command that you wish (e.g. Command + R) >> Click OK

Comment: Any idea how to customize the color? When I use the "Font Color" button, it defaults to the last color I used (orange in my case). When I use this short cut, it always changes the text to red.

Answer (score 1):

There is a relatively easy way to do this

1. open word in mac
2. Go to TOOLS
3. Go to CUSTOMIZE KEYBOAD
4. In the CUSTOMIZE box - Go to ALL COMMANDS
5. In the COMMANDS box - Go to COLOR
6. Choose the colour you want (Start with RED for this example)
7. In the PRESS NEW KEYBOARD SHORT CUT space - hit  +  + r
8. Click ASSIGN key
   9 Then press OK
   you can do all the changes before pressing the OK key

Answer (score 0):

To answer ckb's question on how to customize the color, here is a link that I found can do the trick:
https://wordribbon.tips.net/T004269_Shortcuts_to_Change_Text_Colors.html

Basically, you need to add a Macro and then assign a shortcut to it. Here is the code I am using:

```
Sub FigTab() 
' 
' YourNewMarco 
' MakeTextYellow 
'
  Selection.Font.Color = RGB(196, 89, 17)
End Sub
```

I assigned the shortcut "cmd + Shift + F" to it.